# Access variables in nested classes

Tags: java, class

This is probably a pretty basic question but I can't seem to access the variables from another part of the class I am in. I tried this.p1, this.TwoParamRF.p1, etc etc but I can't get the value of p1 please help. Thanks.

```
   public class SecondMDP {

    public SecondMDP(double p1, double p2) {

        this.rf = new TwoParamRF(p1,p2);

    }

    public static class TwoParamRF implements RewardFunction {
        double p1;
        double p2;

        public TwoParamRF(double p1, double p2) {
            this.p1 = p1;
            this.p2 = p2;
        }
    }   


    public String bestActions(double gamma) {

        ValueIteration vi=computeValue(gamma);
        alert(p1);  //Getting error
        alert(p2);  //here

    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see the field declaration, but it looks like you just need `this.rf.p1` and `this.rf.p2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can't seem to access the variables from another part of the class I am in. I tried this.p1, this.TwoParamRF.p1, etc etc but I can't get the value of p1

The value of *which* `p1`?  You have a static nested class with a member variable of that name, but it's unclear which instance of that class you want to access.

Your outer class's constructor does assign a value of class `TwoParamRF` to an undeclared variable `rf`.  That object has members `p1` and `p2`, which the outer class's `bestActions()` method could, in principle, access.  But it can do so only via a reference of type `TwoParamRF` -- if variable `rf` is instead declared as a `RewardFunction` then you would need to cast it to `TwoParamRF`:

```
((TwoParamRF) rf).p1
```

But of course that's not type safe.  It's a viable approach only if you can rely on `rf` always to be a `TwoParamRF`, in which case it should be declared that way to begin with, or if you test before casting (e.g. via `instanceof`), in which case you need a fallback for when the test fails.

Overall, your code seems to want refactoring.  Supposing that `rf` is indeed declared as a `RewardFunction`, consider what methods you can and should declare for all `RewardFunction`s to implement and their clients to use.  Consider also what part of `bestActions()`' behavior is specific to `TwoParamRF`, and how to move that part into `TwoParamRF`.

Comment: rf was indeed declared as a RewardFunction so I needed to cast it. I missed that and the error didn't point me in that direction. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The only difference between an external class and a nested static class is possible access to class-private static fields. Otherwise, access rules remain the same. The fields `p1` and `p2` belong to an object of the nested class, and are not accessible from an instance of the "parent" class; you will need to reference the `TwoParamRF` object from the parent class. You should consider putting `bestActions()` in the nested class if it only depends on the parameters of the nested class.